# Удаление заданных символов из строки

Tags: c

Дана строка. Нужно получить новую строку, удалив каждый из символов "x" и "y" из данной.

Текущий код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main(void) {
    int i, k;
    char st[] = { };
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(st); i++) {
        if ((st[i] == "x") || (st[i] == "y")) {
            st[i] = "\0";
            printf("%c", st[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще один вариант с заданием удаляемых символов и возможностью как копировать строку, так и менять ее по месту.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Returns: nil terminated dst 
char *
rem_strchrs (char *dst,        // результат
             char *src,        // исходная строка
             const char *chrs  /* строка удаляемых символов */)
{
  int i, j;

  for (i = 0, j = 0; src[i]; i++)
    if (!chrs || !strchr(chrs, src[i]))
      dst[j++] = src[i];

  dst[j] = 0;
  return dst;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  const char *chrs = (const char *)(av[1] ? av[1] : "xy");
  char line[1000];

  while (fputs("Enter: ", stdout), fflush(stdout),
     fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin))
    fputs(rem_strchrs(line, line, chrs), stdout);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Обратите внимание, функция возвращает свой аргумент `dst` (аналогично strcpy() и т.п.), что повышает гибкость ее использования.

Если аргумент `chrs` будет NULL (или пустая строка -- `""`), то rem_strchrs() ведет себя аналогично известой strcpy().

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно выполнить операцию "на месте", то есть изменить исходную строку, то соответствующая функция может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
char * remove_xy( char *s ) 
{ 
    char *q = s; 

    while ( *q && *q != 'x' && *q != 'y' ) ++q; 

    char *p = q; 

    while ( *q ) 
    {
        ++q; 
        if ( *q != 'x' && *q != 'y'  ) *p++ = *q; 
    } 

    return s; 
 }
```

Если не нужно оформлять эту операцию в виде отдельной функции, то вы просто можете включить ее тело в свою программу.

Если нужно скопировать исходную строку в строку назначения, исключив символы 'x' и 'y', то соответствующая функция может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
char * remove_xy( char *s1, const char *s2 ) 
{ 
    char *p = s1; 

    do 
    { 
        if ( *s2 != 'x' && *s2 != 'y'  ) *p++ = *s2; 
    } while ( *s2++ );


    return s1; 
 }
```

Есть еще и третий подход, когда удаляемые символы задаются в качестве параметра в виде отдельной строки. Например,

```
#include <string.h>

//...

char * remove( char *s, const char *t ) 
{ 
    char *q = s; 

    while ( *q && !strchr( t, *q ) ) ++q; 

    char *p = q; 

    while ( *q ) 
    {
        ++q; 
        if ( !strchr( t, *q ) || !*q  ) *p++ = *q; 
    } 

    return s; 
 }
```

Что касается вашего приведенного в вопросе кода, то он не имеет смысла и просто не будет компилироваться.

Answer (score 0):

Только для однобайтных символов!

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned char uchar;


char* remove_of(char* s, const char* cs){
    uchar bits[256] = {0};
    uchar* a, *b, *p;

    p = (uchar*)cs;
    while(*p)
       bits[*p++] = 1;

    for(a = b = (uchar*)s; *a; *a = *b){
       if(! bits[*a])
           ++a;
       ++b;
    }
    return s;
}


int main(void){
    char s[] = "xxxor, xxxxyxya-xyxxyzy";
    puts( remove_of(s, "xy") );
    return 0;
}
```